# Return to first view in UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

When I receive a Push Notification, I want to jump to the middle tab on the tabbar and reset the tab (it has multiple table views that the user may have navigated into). I am able to jump to the tab using tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; ... but how do I reset to the first view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` on a controller class (perhaps your app delegate) and implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` to pop all pushed view controllers off the navigation stack:

```
- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *) tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController {
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```